# Xamarin SIGSEGV error on quick switch

Tags: ios, xamarin, shinobi

My app crashes whenever I try to quickly switch between 3 different views (each one containing some shinobi charts and webview as subviews) via 3 UIButtons. However I don't get any exception trown in my Application Logs.
I am new to Xamarin development and I am trying to fix some issue on an already existing application.
While inspecting the iOS Device Logs I have found a SIGSEGV stacktrace that says:

*"Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
    used by your application."*

If I slowly switch (after something like a second) between the 3 views everything is working fine. I fear there is a problem with the way the views gets *disposed*, maybe the garbage collector fixes the issue by itself if i don't quickly switch the view that gets displayed.

Here it is the iOS Device Logs output:

```
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Warning>: Disposing FinancialTableViewController...
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Warning>: Disposing FinancialLCViewController...
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>: Stacktrace:
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0001c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:45
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:   at LoroPiana.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00009] in /Users/nautessrl/Projects/Monotouch/LoroPianaTMS/Main.cs:18
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:
Native stacktrace:
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    0   LoroPiana                           0x00b7f4a9 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 240
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    1   LoroPiana                           0x00b89781 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 208
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x38e8087b _sigtramp + 42
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    3   UIKit                               0x2e4eca2d <redacted> + 140
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    4   CoreFoundation                      0x2ae4af3f <redacted> + 354
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    5   CoreFoundation                      0x2ad7d208 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    6   UIKit                               0x2e32f82d <redacted> + 84
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    7   UIKit                               0x2e32f765 <redacted> + 24
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    8   UIKit                               0x2e32f71d <redacted> + 64
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    9   UIKit                               0x2e32f26d <redacted> + 104
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    10  UIKit                               0x2e32f0c7 <redacted> + 38
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    11  UIKit                               0x2e32f085 <redacted> + 56
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    12  UIKit                               0x2e32e7d7 <redacted> + 618
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    13  UIKit                               0x2e32e0ed <redacted> + 292
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    14  UIKit                               0x2e32d727 <redacted> + 338
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    15  UIKit                               0x2e437261 <redacted> + 108
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    16  UIKit                               0x2e3361ab <redacted> + 910
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    17  CoreFoundation                      0x2ae4c3e4 <redacted> + 68
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    18  CoreFoundation                      0x2ad79845 <redacted> + 300
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    19  CoreFoundation                      0x2ad7d2c7 <redacted> + 50
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    20  WebKitLegacy                        0x36d9a261 <redacted> + 224
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    21  CoreFoundation                      0x2ae4af3f <redacted> + 354
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    22  CoreFoundation                      0x2ad7d208 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    23  CoreFoundation                      0x2ae4c3e4 <redacted> + 68
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    24  CoreFoundation                      0x2ad79845 <redacted> + 300
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    25  WebCore                             0x362c0c79 <redacted> + 100
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    26  CoreFoundation                      0x2ae0e58f <redacted> + 14
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    27  CoreFoundation                      0x2ae0d99f <redacted> + 218
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    28  CoreFoundation                      0x2ae0c005 <redacted> + 772
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    29  CoreFoundation                      0x2ad5a621 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    30  CoreFoundation                      0x2ad5a433 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    31  GraphicsServices                    0x320a00a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    32  UIKit                               0x2e345359 UIApplicationMain + 1440
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    33  LoroPiana                           0x00441ab0 wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 272
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    34  LoroPiana                           0x003f7c98 MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 52
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    35  LoroPiana                           0x003f7c58 MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 204
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    36  LoroPiana                           0x0015e000 LoroPiana_Application_Main_string__ + 208
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    37  LoroPiana                           0x005ca8a4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    38  LoroPiana                           0x00b8b97b mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1158
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    39  LoroPiana                           0x00bd38e9 mono_runtime_invoke + 88
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    40  LoroPiana                           0x00bd6e0b mono_runtime_exec_main + 282
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    41  LoroPiana                           0x00bd6c53 mono_runtime_run_main + 438
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    42  LoroPiana                           0x00b75d29 mono_jit_exec + 48
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    43  LoroPiana                           0x00c207fc monotouch_main + 2292
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    44  LoroPiana                           0x00b58aed main + 108
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:    45  LoroPiana                           0x0015df1c start + 40
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes LoroPiana[4675] <Error>:
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes ReportCrash[4677] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
Oct 15 12:40:36 Meraxes ReportCrash[4677] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 4675
```

Where should I start inspecting this kind of issue?

I am current developing on a retina ipad mini with iOS 8.0.2 using Xamarin 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that two views out of three got Disposed twice.
Fixing that solved my issue.

Comment: This is the exact problem I'am fighting with for 2 days now. Could you please help me? What do you mean with "got disposed twice" ??? I'am relatively new to iOS.

Comment: You call .Dispose() on the object and allow the garbage collector to free its allocated memory.

Comment: But I never call this by myself. My View is called via a segue in the storyboard. "Dispose()" is only called in the "ReleaseDesignerOutlets()" Method in .designer.cs file. Thank you very much that you help me!

Comment: I suggest you to use the Xcode Instruments tool after you installed the your app on the device and keep track of memory allocation and zombies while you profile the app.

Comment: It has not helped me. So you call your views not with a segue?